# Azure App Service Plan: configure load balancing

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-web-apps, azure-app-services

We have an auto-scaling App Service Plan, which consists of 2 Web Apps:

- One web app is accessed by the public, and should be load balanced.
- However, the other web app (authoring) for support reasons (data integrity) can only be accessed from a single instance.

Is it possible to configure on a web app level that all requests to this authoring web app would be directed only to a **single** instance, while the public web app is being load balanced?

We're trying to avoid having to configure 2 different App Service Plans for it, as this would mean additional costs. It would be beneficial if we didn't have to run a dedicated App Service Plan for the authoring environment, which is only accessed once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

I think to have found an answer to my own question. I believe the per-app scaling feature would meet my goal: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-scale-per-app.

I would set up the authoring app with a NumberOfWorkers set to 1, while the publishing app can have a higher NumberofWorkers set.